# How to delete a message from Notes outgoing queue

Tags: email, lotus-notes

I attached a couple of zip files to an email without noticing how large they are (42 MB each, making that email 84 MB). I realized my mistake when Notes began to sync and was taking forever, so I stopped the sync.

But there doesn't appear to be any way to remove emails from the outgoing queue, or to even view that queue.

Is there a way to delete that message from the outgoing queue? I don't care if it's completely lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a database in your datapath called "mail.box".
All outgoing Mail of your client will go through this database, if they are sent while "offline".

When you delete the document there, it will not get replicated to you server, thus not getting sent.

Answer (score 1):

@Kyze is correct about the mail.box file. You don't even really have to open it and delete the specific message. You can just shut down Notes, then find the mail.box file on your hard drive (frequently C:\Program Files(x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data\mail.box, but your installation may be elsewhere) and delete it.  Notes will automatically create a new one when you restart it.